# android fails to open file using intent ACTION_VIEW. On failure, it makes a toast saying couldn't find item. No error thrown into the logs either

Tags: android, kotlin

here is my current code -

```
/**
 * takes list of keys and the file to open. decrypts the file and opens it using context it
 * received as a parameter
 * @param keyList takes list of keys used for encryption and decryption.
 * @param safeFile the file to open from safe
 */
fun openFile(
    keyList: List<SecretKey>,
    safeFile: SafeFiles,
    context: Context,
    layoutInflater: LayoutInflater
) {
    //FILE TO BE OPENED
    val decryptedFile = File(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "$safeAbsoluteLocation/$cacheDirectoryName/${decryptedFileName}${safeFile.extension}"
    )
    readFromWriteTo(//WRITES DATA TO THE FILE
        from = safeFile,
        destinationFile = decryptedFile,
        keyList = keyList,
        context = context,
        layoutInflater = layoutInflater
    )
    saveChangesToLogFile(//ignore this
        action = "open file",
        string = "File directory opened - ${safeFile.fileDirectory}, " +
                "file extension ${safeFile.fileDirectory}, " +
                "file size - ${safeFile.fileSize}"
    )
    Log.d(TAG, "file path = ${decryptedFile.absolutePath}")
    val uri: Uri = Uri.fromFile(decryptedFile).normalizeScheme()
    val mime = MimeTypeMap
        .getSingleton()
        .getMimeTypeFromExtension(safeFile.extension.substring(1))
    Log.d(TAG, "mime = $mime")
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.data = uri
    intent.type = mime
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open file with"))
}
```

Here's what I can verify for you - While starting the intent the file exists with the correct data already written to it I navigated to the location and checked for myself. Also, You can see the log outputs -

```
2022-07-12 11:11:09.746 27981-28096/com.example.cryptile D/SafeData: file path = /storage/emulated/0/Cryptile/CRYPTILE_2022_07_09/.CACHE/8aa605f3-b394-4ccc-bd93-6408eb01989d.png
2022-07-12 11:11:09.752 27981-28096/com.example.cryptile D/SafeData: mime = image/png
```

The issue I face is that the file isn't opened and I get a Toast saying `couldn't find item` and, there's no error thrown into the logs either.

log of uri -

```
2022-07-12 17:47:57.286 14505-14631/com.example.cryptile D/SafeData: uri = content://com.example.cryptile.fileProvider/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0/Cryptile/CRYPTILE_2022_07_09/.CACHE/099bdf37-a68b-4a34-8f77-fe25046579b3.png
```

Comment: try to check in debug

Comment: try adding intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

Comment: @mohit48 I tried that. Didn't change anything.

Comment: @ramesh I tried stopping the app just before launching the activity and then checked for if the file wasn't proper. No issues there either.

Comment: check the same path or file is available or not in storage or try to change file format may be work

Comment: @ramesh I have checked the path. it isn't the issue. I have also tried different formats like for audios, text files, etc.

Comment: can you print the log of uri? Also try getting the uri by using FileProvider.

Comment: @mohit48 I have added the log of uri. the file name is randomly generated and then bytes are added. So, they are different every time. Also, I had preveously tried file provider with all the stuff added to the manifest. same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently this is how I use the intent -

```
fileOpener = { file: File ->
    val uri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        requireContext(),
        "com.example.cryptile.fileProvider",
        file
    )
    val mime = MimeTypeMap
        .getSingleton()
        .getMimeTypeFromExtension(safeFile.extension.substring(1))
    Log.d(TAG, "mime = $mime")

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime)
    Log.d(
        TAG, "data received:" +
                "uri = $uri\n" +
                "extension = ${safeFile.extension.substring(1)}\n" +
                "path = ${file.absolutePath}\n" +
                "size = ${file.totalSpace} "
    )
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        context!!.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

and it works. Probably `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` made the most difference.